# How fetch data from a mysql database using ajax (laravel)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

How fetch data from a mysql database using ajax (laravel)? How to update the block dynamically .message_box

**AJAX**

```
$(function () {

$.ajax({
    url: "",
    dataType: 'html',

    success: function(responce){
        $('.message_box').html(responce); // this div to be updated
    }
});
```

});

**Blade**

```
<div class="message_box">

    @foreach($message as $content)
        {{ $content->message }}
    @endforeach

</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function chat()
{
    $message = MessageModel::orderBy('id')->get();
    return view('chat.chat', ['message' => $message]);
}
```

Updated code

Comment: Where is the database query? What is the problem?

Comment: @Vohuman, Updated code

Answer (score 3):

Did you add a url to your ajax request?

## Routes

```
Route::get('/chat', 'ChatController@chat');
```

## AJAX

```
      function update() {
        $.ajax({
           url: "/chat",
           dataType: 'html',

           success: function(responce){
               $('.message_box').html(responce);
           }
        });
    }

    $('#send_message').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "post",
            url: "/chat",
            context: this,
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            cache: false,
            async: true,

            success: function () {
                $('#message').val('');
                update();
            },

            error: function () {
                alert('Сообщение не было отправлено');
            }
        });

    });
```

Comment: yes, but .message_box is not updated (if add new content).

Comment: the ajax is being called only once; when the page first loads. Is the chat in real time?

Comment: Are you using additional code, or is this the only code you are using for a real time chat? Are you using node?

Comment: If you want the chat to update when you click send message, then you can just call the update method as shown about. But if you want to chat with other users, then I suggest looking at nodejs and socket.io.

Comment: hm, sorry, but, div.message_box not refreshing :( (copy + past)

Comment: What is the response returned from the ajax?

Comment: You need to set the dataType to html instead of json.

Comment: [link](http://i67.fastpic.ru/big/2015/1226/22/1e95459d35da00072805c76bcd149e22.png), changed, lol :)